# How to select the test I want to run via Nightwatch Programmatic API

Tags: javascript, selenium, express, nightwatch.js

I am currently working on creating a web app that allows me to run Nightwatch tests from a graphic interface. Right now I can run all my tests with a post request from my web app I am using Nightwatch Programmatic API.
My question is can I chose the folder of tests I want to run from a post request, here is my code,
Thank you.

```
router.post('/exec', function (req, res) {

Nightwatch.cli(function (argv) {
    argv.config = 'nightwatch.conf.js';
    argv.source= 'folder of tests i want to run';
    const runner = Nightwatch.CliRunner(argv);

    runner
        .setup()
        .startWebDriver()
        .then(() => {
            return runner.runTests()
        })
        .then(() => {
            return runner.stopWebDriver()
        })
        .catch(err => console.error(err));
   });
})
```

Comment: are you asking about passing the folder path where tests are available?

Comment: hey, @Raju 
no, what I want exactly is to run individual tests via the Nightwatch Programmatic API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you know, the config file is exported as an object. If you are able to read the file contents and store it into a variable, you can try to override the property `src_folders`.

```
const red = require('../nightwatch.conf');
console.log(red.src_folders)
```

Comment: hey, Thanks that was helpful what I am really looking for is to run a single test, I know that we use --testcase "name of the test" in cli but how can we do that with the Programmatic API. thanks

Comment: is it like you have to run all the tests from `src_folders` and then an extra one?

Comment: no just one test like this:  node nightwatch.js tests/acceptance/usecases/admin/login.js  --testcase "log in with the wrong username". this example is what we do in normal nightwatch runner and I want the same but with the programmatic API. Thank you